# get a specific element from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows and i want to get any specific element from this array: array is stored in a variable as.

```
   $results = 

        Array
           (
        [0] => stdClass Object
                         (
        [id] => 1
        [calendar] => 1
        [time] => 2016-01-22 17:25:28
        [booked_time] => 01/22/2016 11:00
        [booked_time_unformatted] => 2016-01-22 11:00:00
        [name] => Shoaib
        [email] => shoaib@techleadz.com
        [phone] => 0987654321
        [question] => 123
        [quantity] => 1
        [buffered_date] => a:9:{s:5:"PRICE";s:2:"25";s:10:"COUPONCODE";s:0:"";s:8:"QUANTITY";N;s:4:"NAME";s:6:"Shoaib";s:5:"EMAIL";s:20:"shoaib@techleadz.com";s:5:"PHONE";s:10:"0987654321";s:8:"COMMENTS";s:3:"123";s:4:"DATE";s:10:"01/22/2016";s:4:"TIME";s:5:"11:00";}
        [submitted] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [calendar] => 1
        [time] => 2016-01-23 10:39:30
        [booked_time] => 01/25/2016 15:00
        [booked_time_unformatted] => 2016-01-25 15:00:00
        [name] => Shoaib
        [email] => shoaib@techleadz.com
        [phone] => 0987654321
        [question] => dsadasd
        [quantity] => 1
        [buffered_date] => a:9:{s:5:"PRICE";s:2:"25";s:10:"COUPONCODE";s:0:"";s:8:"QUANTITY";N;s:4:"NAME";s:6:"Shoaib";s:5:"EMAIL";s:20:"shoaib@techleadz.com";s:5:"PHONE";s:10:"0987654321";s:8:"COMMENTS";s:7:"dsadasd";s:4:"DATE";s:10:"01/25/2016";s:4:"TIME";s:5:"15:00";}
        [submitted] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [calendar] => 1
        [time] => 2016-01-23 11:27:22
        [booked_time] => 01/25/2016 11:00
        [booked_time_unformatted] => 2016-01-25 11:00:00
        [name] => test
        [email] => shoaib@techleadz.com
        [phone] => 0987654321
        [question] => asfas
        [quantity] => 1
        [buffered_date] => a:9:{s:5:"PRICE";s:2:"25";s:10:"COUPONCODE";s:0:"";s:8:"QUANTITY";N;s:4:"NAME";s:4:"test";s:5:"EMAIL";s:20:"shoaib@techleadz.com";s:5:"PHONE";s:10:"0987654321";s:8:"COMMENTS";s:5:"asfas";s:4:"DATE";s:10:"01/25/2016";s:4:"TIME";s:5:"11:00";}
        [submitted] => 0
    )

            )
```

Now i have an array like this so how i can get the the value for [submitted] foreach element in this array.

Comment: What does `specific` mean?

Comment: `$results[6]`, `$results[6]->name;`.

Comment: Why the 6tx, and not the 5th, for example?

Comment: specific element like:  [submitted]

Comment: just iterate the array with foreach, `foreach($results as $result) echo $result->submitted;`

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear what you need. What about `[submitted]`? Do you need to extract the elements that have this property set to false?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an array . This is a [StdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)  Object

To access information in stdClass

```
 $results[6]->submitted;
```

Comment: owh! :-/ sorry my bad :-/ .

Answer (score 1):

To randomly access a specific field use

```
echo $results[0]->submitted;
echo $results[0]->quantity;
echo $results[1]->submitted;
echo $results[1]->quantity;
```

Using a foreach loop

```
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    echo $result->submitted . '<br>';  

    echo $result->booked_time . '<br>';
    echo $result->name . '<br>';
    echo $result->time . '<br>';
    echo $result->email . '<br>';
}
```